# how can I access an element within a json object with Python?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have a json object returned from an elasticsearch query as follows:

```
{"took": 10, "timed_out": false, "_shards": {"total": 5, "successful":   5, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0}, "hits": {"total": 1, "max_score": 0.5753642, "hits": [{"_index": "match", "_type": "score", "_id": "J_J1zGcBjpp4O0gQqUq_", "_score": 0.5753642, "_source": {"tournament_id": 1, "board_number": "2", "nsp": "1", "ewp": "8", "contract": "3C", "by": "N", "tricks": "9", "nsscore": "110", "ewscore": "0", "timestamp": "2018-12-20T16:32:02.440315"}}]}}
```

I need to access the "nsscore" element. When I try the following:

```
print(["hits"]["hits"]["_source"]["nsscore"])
```

I get the following error:

```
print(["hits"]["hits"]["_source"]["nsscore"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Wht is the correct way to access this element? Thank you!

Comment: You've left off the variable name which you're using for this dictionary, which should go before the first index (`"hints"`). Python thinks you're trying to do stuff to the singleton list `["hits"]`

Comment: JSON is just deserialized to lists and dictionaries. It's nothing mysterious. Somewhere in that, you need a list index.

Comment: "hits" has a list stored against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a variable name here.
For example, if:

```
variable = {"took": 10, "timed_out": false, "_shards": {"total": 5, "successful":   5, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0}, "hits": {"total": 1, "max_score": 0.5753642, "hits": [{"_index": "match", "_type": "score", "_id": "J_J1zGcBjpp4O0gQqUq_", "_score": 0.5753642, "_source": {"tournament_id": 1, "board_number": "2", "nsp": "1", "ewp": "8", "contract": "3C", "by": "N", "tricks": "9", "nsscore": "110", "ewscore": "0", "timestamp": "2018-12-20T16:32:02.440315"}}]}}
```

Then:

```
print(variable["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["nsscore"])
```

Comment: Ah yes, few mistakes, but I was just stating that there was no variable in the question, so it could not work.

Comment: You're right that this looks like the wrong sequence of keys - but I assume it was just copied from the OP, and likely not checked. The main point stands, that the OP's first issue is not including the variable name.

Comment: resp = es.search(index="match", body=query) 
 data = json.dumps(resp)
 print(data["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["nsscore"])
I still get error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I agree straw's solution should work but it doesn't. Thank you for your comments and time.

Comment: thank you, I tried as suggested above by angelwally and I get this: TypeError: string indices must be integers. I also tried print(variable["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["nsscore"]) which also does not work.

Comment: Could you print again the results inside `data` in your previous comment? `print(data)`

Comment: {"took": 9, "timed_out": false, "_shards": {"total": 5, "successful": 5, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0}, "hits": {"total": 1, "max_score": 0.5753642, "hits": [{"_index": "match", "_type": "score", "_id": "J_J1zGcBjpp4O0gQqUq_", "_score": 0.5753642, "_source": {"tournament_id": 1, "board_number": "2", "nsp": "1", "ewp": "8", "contract": "3C", "by": "N", "tricks": "9", "nsscore": "110", "ewscore": "0", "timestamp": "2018-12-20T16:32:02.440315"}}]}}

Comment: Well I don't understand where it does not work. Could you try to print level by level? like `print(data["hits"])`, then `print(data["hits"]["hits"])`, etc... to see where it fails.

Comment: thank you. Fails immediately on data["hits"] TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Oh I think I got it! You're doing `json.dumps` instead of `json.loads`. So you don't have a dictionary but a string!

Comment: I tried that: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict' I have also tried with neither loads nor dumps

Comment: Could you try `print(resp["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["nsscore"])` then? (no json loads or dumps)

Comment: I am doing without loads or dumps and this: {'tournament_id': 1, 'board_number': '2', 'nsp': '1', 'ewp': '8', 'contract': '3C', 'by': 'N', 'tricks': '9', 'nsscore': '110', 'ewscore': '0', 'timestamp': '2018-12-20T16:32:02.440315'} is produced by print(resp["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"])

Comment: Then do `resp["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["nsscore"]` and you'll have your score!

Comment: print(resp["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["nsscore"]) this produces 110 which is what I want. Thank you I am very grateful for your time, wisdom and help. No need to sued json loads/dumps

Comment: I am trying to do a bridge tournament scoring app - this is the beginning it's going to get much more difficult!